# Google Analytics plugin

Tags: monaca, cordova

初めて投稿させていただきます。

https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin
Monaca で Google Analytics plugin をインストールしたのですが、Androidのビルドに失敗します。
Monaca Cloudの中でadtの場所が見つからないようですが、どなたか解決された方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
プラグイン側でなんとかできるのか、Monaca Cloudで対応するしか方法がないのか、切り分けができれば今後の対応もしやすいです。

以下エラー

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-google-analytics':Error: Uh oh!
cannot find "/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+/project.properties" referenced in <;framework>
    at Object.AndroidProject.addSubProject (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/android-project.js:70:51)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:110:27)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Error: Uh oh!
cannot find "/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+/project.properties" referenced in <;framework>
    at Object.AndroidProject.addSubProject (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/android-project.js:70:51)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:110:27)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Build error: Error building project source code
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらくCordovaのバージョンが低いためにビルドエラーを起こしているものを思われます。
11/25にCordova5へMonacaがアップデートするようですので、
Cordova5にアップグレードした後に再度試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
アップデートを待ってもう一度ビルドしてみます。

11/25にアップデートする情報はこちらには届いていないのですが、どちらで通知されておりますでしょうか？一般には通知されていないとしたら、CURRENTのMLあたりでしょうか？

Comment: 11/17に配信されているMonaca Newsletterからのメールで11月25日午後8時～を予定してアップデートを行うとあります。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
遅ればせながら、Newsletterに登録しました。

今朝までブログなかったのですが、Cordova5の記事が先ほど公開されたようですね。
http://blog.asial.co.jp/1453